# How to populate Signer Name text field in document via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I have a document in Word and PDF format that I am using with embedded signing via the REST API. The document has a Signer Name, Signature, and Date lines. 
Is it possible to add the SignerName next to the Signer Name label on my document from the API?

Modifying the document before adding to an envelope each time is not an ideal solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use Anchor String strategy or PDF Field form transformation if you are using Fillable Form PDF. More details are available [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs) how each approach works.